# Time required to build node OSX/Cabal

Tags: cardano-node, node

I'm setting up a node on my mac. It's been stuck on "Building     network-3.1.2.1 (all, legacy fallback)" for a couple of hours now.

Is this normal, or have I got something wrong?

Thanks[image]

Comment: Could you please give some more details on what you're doing? How did you set up your node (Daedalus, built from source, IOHK binaries...)? And maybe a screenshot would be helpful too.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for the response. I'm installing the node from source https://docs.cardano.org/projects/cardano-node/en/latest/getting-started/install.html - I'll add a screenshot to the original post. - Thanks again.

Comment: Building the node can take a while, but from my experience it shouldn't take hours even on a less powerful system. If you just want to start a node, you can also try to use the pre-built binaries from https://hydra.iohk.io/job/Cardano/cardano-node/cardano-node-macos/latest-finished

Comment: @eddex- Thanks again for your help. I've tried to use the prebuilt binary but it's returning the error bash: command ‘?? is not installed; please install it and try again"

Comment: I'd advise to head over to https://t.me/CardanoStakePoolWorkgroup on Telegram and ask for help there, maybe mention what sort of machine spec (e.g. how much memory you have) you're dealing with and what version of ghc / cabal you're trying to build the cardano-node code with. FYI Mac binaries for latest stable release can be found here: https://hydra.iohk.io/build/6263000/download/1/cardano-node-1.27.0-macos.tar.gz

Comment: Hi @HomerJ - Thanks for the response. I've tried building using the binary and am getting error: path '/var/folders/yy/bd1g3c_53z1_hf67hnb5j7n40000gn/T/' has a trailing slash

Answer (score 1):

I strongly urge you to consider building using nix. I apologize if this wasn't the answer you were asking for, but it is probably the best solution for building the Cardano node.

I went through so many issues when trying to build from source it would make this issue seem trivial. Also, would like to note that by adding the binaries in step 2, I shaved 4hrs off the build time, and that is on a machine with a AMD 3900XT with 12 cores. Building without binaries on an average machine could take upwards of 12hrs.

https://docs.cardano.org/projects/cardano-node/en/latest/getting-started/building-the-node-using-nix.html

**By using nix to build the Cardano node, you really only have 3 steps to follow:**

1.

```
curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install > install-nix.sh 
chmod +x install nix.sh
./install-nix.sh
```

2. sudo mkdir -p /etc/nix
   cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/nix/nix.conf
   substituters = https://cache.nixos.org https://hydra.iohk.io
   trusted-public-keys = iohk.cachix.org-1:DpRUyj7h7V830dp/i6Nti+NEO2/nhblbov/8MW7Rqoo= hydra.iohk.io:f/Ea+s+dFdN+3Y/G+FDgSq+a5NEWhJGzdjvKNGv0/EQ= cache.nixos.org-1:6NCHdD59X431o0gWypbMrAURkbJ16ZPMQFGspcDShjY=
   EOF
3. 

```
git clone https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node
cd cardano-node
nix-build -A scripts.mainnet.node -o mainnet-node-local
./mainnet-node-local
```

Again, sorry if this wasn't the solution to build the cardano node using but I had nothing but problems using Cabal during the Plutus Pioneer Program.

Good luck!

Comment: Only to confirm that the first times I built cardano-node without the IOHK binary cache set for nix, it was taking more than 10 hours.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me. Unfortunately still no joy. I got all the way through the installation using the method you stated above and still was unable to access the CLI. Am I being thick or is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little? Was nix successfully installed via step 1? If so, did you add the binaries in step 2 properly?

Answer (score 0):

Something definitely wrong. I can build `node` from scratch (with a clean cabal cache) in about an hour (on Linux x86_64). Not sure how long this would take on an M1 Mac.

I also disagree with [/u/intrinsic-values](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/users/1894/intrinsic-values) on the Nix issue. IMO, Nix solves some problems that I do not have and creates a bunch of new problems.